# Form ajaxSubmit Serialize

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hi guys i have a problem with my form in ajax, i am using [ajaxSubmit](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) because i need upload files in the form, so this is my jquery code for the forms:

```
var send_form = function(form_id, btn_id, fail_id, done_id){
    var sending_contact_form = false;
    var contact_captcha = $('.codecatch').text();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".botCode").each(function(){
            $(this).val(contact_captcha);
        });
    }, 3000);
    $(form_id).submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        var form = $(this).ajaxSubmit({});
        if ($(".codecatch").html() == $(".botCode").val() ) {
            if(!sending_contact_form){
                sending_contact_form = true;
                var action = $(this).attr('action');
                var btn = $(this).find(btn_id);
                btn.val($(btn_id).data('sending'));
                var xhr = form.data('jqxhr');
                xhr.fail(function(){
                    $(done_id).fadeOut();
                    $(fail_id).fadeIn();
                }).done(function(data){
                    btn.val($(btn_id).data('send'));
                    $(fail_id).fadeOut();
                    $(done_id).fadeIn().css("display","inline-block");
                    //$(this).trigger("reset");
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(done_id).fadeOut();
                    }, 3000 );
                    sending_contact_form = false;
                },'json');

            }
        }else{
            $(done_id).fadeOut();
            $(fail_id).fadeIn().css("display","inline-block");
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(fail_id).fadeOut();
            }, 3000 );
        }
        return false;
    });
}
```

This is my code for form process

```
if(count($_POST)>0 && $_POST['f_codecatch'] == $contact_captcha_code){
    $attachments = [];
    if(!empty($_FILES)){
        $files = $_FILES;   // file array
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $path = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/files/';  //upload dir.
            if(!is_dir($path)) { mkdir($path); }
            $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file ,$path);
            $attachments[] = $path . $file['name'];
        }
    }
    $msg = '';
    $msg .= '<html><body>';
    $msg .= '<div style="padding-top: 30px;padding-right: 20%;padding-left: 20%;">';
        $msg .= '<div style="width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; margin-bottom: 20px;">';
            $msg .= '<img src="'.THEME_PATH.'/images/logo-atiker.png" width="250px" alt="Atiker México" title="Atiker México">';
        $msg .= '</div>';
        if (!empty($_POST['f_name'])) {
            $msg .= '<div style="display: -webkit-box;display: -webkit-flex;display: -ms-flexbox;display: flex;width: 100%;padding: 10px;-webkit-justify-content: space-around;-ms-flex-pack: distribute;justify-content: space-around;-webkit-box-align: center;-webkit-align-items: center;-ms-flex-align: center;align-items: center;border-top: 1px dashed #c3c3c3;">';
                $msg .= '<div style="-webkit-box-flex: 1;-webkit-flex: 1;-ms-flex: 1;flex: 1;font-weight: 700;">';
                    $msg .= 'Nombre:';
                $msg .= '</div>';
                $msg .= '<div style="-webkit-box-flex: 1;-webkit-flex: 1;-ms-flex: 1;flex: 1;color: #6b6b6b;font-weight: 700;">';
                    $msg .= htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_name']);
                $msg .= '</div>';
            $msg .= '</div>';
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['f_email'])) {
            $msg .= '<div style="display: -webkit-box;display: -webkit-flex;display: -ms-flexbox;display: flex;width: 100%;padding: 10px;-webkit-justify-content: space-around;-ms-flex-pack: distribute;justify-content: space-around;-webkit-box-align: center;-webkit-align-items: center;-ms-flex-align: center;align-items: center;border-top: 1px dashed #c3c3c3;">';
                $msg .= '<div style="-webkit-box-flex: 1;-webkit-flex: 1;-ms-flex: 1;flex: 1;font-weight: 700;">';
                    $msg .='Email:';
                $msg .= '</div>';
                $msg .= '<div style="-webkit-box-flex: 1;-webkit-flex: 1;-ms-flex: 1;flex: 1;color: #6b6b6b;font-weight: 700;">';
                    $msg .= htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_email']);
                $msg .= '</div>';
            $msg .= '</div>';
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['f_phone'])) {
            $msg .= '<div style="display: -webkit-box;display: -webkit-flex;display: -ms-flexbox;display: flex;width: 100%;padding: 10px;-webkit-justify-content: space-around;-ms-flex-pack: distribute;justify-content: space-around;-webkit-box-align: center;-webkit-align-items: center;-ms-flex-align: center;align-items: center;border-top: 1px dashed #c3c3c3;">';
                $msg .= '<div style="-webkit-box-flex: 1;-webkit-flex: 1;-ms-flex: 1;flex: 1;font-weight: 700;">';
                    $msg .= 'Teléfono:';
                $msg .= '</div>';
                $msg .= '<div style="-webkit-box-flex: 1;-webkit-flex: 1;-ms-flex: 1;flex: 1;color: #6b6b6b;font-weight: 700;">';
                    $msg .= htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_phone']);
                $msg .= '</div>';
            $msg .= '</div>';
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['f_type'])) {
            $msg .= '<div style="display: -webkit-box;display: -webkit-flex;display: -ms-flexbox;display: flex;width: 100%;padding: 10px;-webkit-justify-content: space-around;-ms-flex-pack: distribute;justify-content: space-around;-webkit-box-align: center;-webkit-align-items: center;-ms-flex-align: center;align-items: center;border-top: 1px dashed #c3c3c3;">';
                $msg .= '<div style="-webkit-box-flex: 1;-webkit-flex: 1;-ms-flex: 1;flex: 1;font-weight: 700;">';
                    $msg .= 'Tipo de Cotización:';
                $msg .= '</div>';
                $msg .= '<div style="-webkit-box-flex: 1;-webkit-flex: 1;-ms-flex: 1;flex: 1;color: #6b6b6b;font-weight: 700;">';
                    $msg .= htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_type']);
                $msg .= '</div>';
            $msg .= '</div>';
        }
        if (!empty($_POST['f_model'])) {
            $msg .= '<div style="display: -webkit-box;display: -webkit-flex;display: -ms-flexbox;display: flex;width: 100%;padding: 10px;-webkit-justify-content: space-around;-ms-flex-pack: distribute;justify-content: space-around;-webkit-box-align: center;-webkit-align-items: center;-ms-flex-align: center;align-items: center;border-top: 1px dashed #c3c3c3;">';
                $msg .= '<div style="-webkit-box-flex: 1;-webkit-flex: 1;-ms-flex: 1;flex: 1;font-weight: 700;">';
                    $msg .='Año y Modelo:';
                $msg .= '</div>';
                $msg .= '<div style="-webkit-box-flex: 1;-webkit-flex: 1;-ms-flex: 1;flex: 1;color: #6b6b6b;font-weight: 700;">';
                    $msg .= htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_model']);
                $msg .= '</div>';
            $msg .= '</div>';
        }
    $msg .= '</div>';
    $msg .= '</body></html>';
    $to = 'myemail';//htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_email']);
    $subject = htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_name']).' <'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_email']).'>';
    $body = $msg;
    $headers = array(
            'From:'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_name']).' <'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_email']).'>',
            'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8',
            'Reply-To:'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_name']).' <'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_email']).'>'
        );
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers, $attachments);
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>true));
    exit;
}
```

I already get the email fine but that come in format plain html, is for the header content or what is your suggest because i already try many things xD, thanks for any help

This is the email i get

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the headers this the correct way for the accents and more, thanks for any help :D

```
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0):

have you used 
enctype="multipart/form-data" 
in form tag

Comment: Yes i already included

<form id="c-contact-form-modal" name="contact-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: sry i suppose you have error in file uploading but now i have read full post and you are asking that html is not visible in mail
pls try changing 
$header variable using - 

'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'

Comment: Thanks You give me the right way for the correct answer, this work fine for the accents too 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'